# How can i make this grid layout always stay the same size bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a grid layout with images inside, The images aren't always the same size, Some of them seem to make the layout of the grid slightly smaller and i can't figure out a way to get them all the same size.

Here's the HTML.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="row">
  <h2>Handheld Consoles</h2>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="tile purple text-center">
        <h3 class="title">Nintendo 3DS</h3>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-height:128px; max-width:128px" src="../images/3ds.png" /></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="tile red text-center">
        <h3 class="title">Nintendo GBA</h3>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-height:128px; max-width:128px" src="../images/gba.png" /></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="tile orange text-center">
        <h3 class="title">Nintendo 64</h3>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-height:128px; max-width:128px" src="../images/n64.png" /></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="tile green text-center">
        <h3 class="title">Sony PSP</h3>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-height:128px; max-width:128px" src="../images/psp.png" /></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS.

```
.tile {  
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;       
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color:#fff;
} 
.title {
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align:center;
}
.purple {
    background: #5133AB;
}
.purple:hover {
    background: #3e2784;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe if you just set the `height` of class `.tile`, it should work

```
.tile {  
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;       
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color:#fff;
    height: 200px; // or whatever height you want all the tiles to be
}
```

Comment: Ah, that seems to have worked lol, Not quite sure why i didn't try that must of tried just about everything else.